# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService

Tags: javascript, jwt, nestjs

I have created some modules here but i am facing an error

Auth module

```
   import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { LocalStrategy } from "./local.strategy";
import { JwtStrategy } from "./jwt.strategy";
import { UsersModule } from "../users/users.module";
import { PassportModule } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { JwtModule, JwtService } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { jwtConstants } from "./constants";
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

@Module({
    imports: [
        UsersModule,
        PassportModule,
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: jwtConstants.secret,
            signOptions: { expiresIn: "1d" },
        }),
    ],
    providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
    exports: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Email module

```
  import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import EmailService from "./email.service";

import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";

import { EmailConfirmationService } from "./emailConfirmation.service";
import { EmailConfirmationController } from "./emailConfirmation.controller";
import { EmailConfirmationGuard } from "./guards/emailConfirmation.guard";
import { AuthModule } from "src/auth/auth.module";
import { UsersModule } from "src/users/users.module";

@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule,AuthModule,UsersModule],
    providers: [EmailService,EmailConfirmationService,EmailConfirmationGuard],
    exports: [EmailConfirmationService,EmailConfirmationGuard],
    controllers : [EmailConfirmationController]
})
export class EmailModule {}
```

User module

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { UsersService } from "./users.service";
import { UsersController } from "./users.controller";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { UserSchema } from "./entities/user.entity";
import { EmailModule } from "src/email/email.module";

@Module({
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: "User", schema: UserSchema }]),EmailModule],
    providers: [UsersService],
    exports: [UsersService],
    controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Error I am facing

```
 [Nest] 9200  - 09/26/2021, 3:43:15 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot create the EmailModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the EmailModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule -> AuthModule -> UsersModule]
Error: Nest cannot create the EmailModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the EmailModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.
```

What am i missing ?

```
EmailConfirmationService is used in UsersController
UserService is used in EmailConfirmationService
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use EmailService in you UserController and also UserService is used in EmailConfirmationService then you have to do something like this in UserModule:

```
imports: [forwardRef(() => EmailModule)]
```

and inside the EmailModule do the same thing for the UserModule:

```
imports: [forwardRef(() => UserModule)]
```

Rest of the imports should be without the forwardRef(()=>)

you can read more about circular dependency here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency

Answer (score 5):

You have `JwtService` listed in your imports. Imports are for modules only.

Share the code from `JwtService` as well so that we can make sure there are no other issues.

Update:
If the `EmailModule` wants to use the exports from the `AuthModule` (JwtService in this case), it must add the `AuthModule` to its imports array.

This is the entire premise of the DI system, modules share things between eachother by placing the thing they intend to share in the `exports` array. After that, any module can add the Source module to its `imports` array to gain access to the things that the source exported. The error message literally spells it out for you:

`If JwtService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within EmailModule?   @Module({     imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtService */ ]   })`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target in `tsconfig.json` is es6.